# Getting lat/lng from wkid, latestwkid and x y coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, geocoding

I am receiving some JSON feed with this data

```
"geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
"spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100,
    "latestWkid": 3857
  },
```

and set of coordinates like

```
"geometry": {
   "x": -11696523.780400001,
   "y": 4804891.0001000017
}
```

If there a way to convert this x and y to lat/lng which I can use in Google Maps?

I have read some references but there either I can`t see the answer, or it's goes very deep into GIS terminology which I just can't afford to learn at the moment.

Comment: Is all your data in : "latestWkid": 3857? How do you want to change it? Have you looked at Projecting it to Lat-long using Python & proj4?

Comment: There nothing I can change, so I assume all data in `"latestWkid": 3857` whatever it means. I briefly looked documentation for Proj4, and well it's very dark forest for me,I mean there are some information for "unit conversions" but no examples whatsoever.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify what GIS tool(s) you have available, and what you have tried. Stating that you can't be bothered to learn is rather disturbing.

Comment: I fully understand disturbing part. There is answer bellow I accepted, it's all I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the ArcGIS server REST endpoint to convert to wkid 4326 (lat/lon). Here's a URL for one of Esri's sample servers:

https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=102100&outSR=4326&geometries=%7B%0D%0A++%22geometryType%22+%3A+%22esriGeometryPoint%22%2C%0D%0A++%22geometries%22+%3A+%5B%0D%0A+++++%7B%0D%0A+++++++%22x%22+%3A+-11696523.780400001%2C+%0D%0A+++++++%22y%22+%3A+4804891.0001000017%0D%0A+++++%7D%0D%0A++%5D%0D%0A%7D&f=HTML

[image: ArcGIS projection engine]

Pasting the coordinate in google maps gives you this (Littleton, right?):

https://maps.google.com/?q=39.5785846502541+-105.071660830008

If you just need to convert the occasional coordinate this will work fine, but I guess as soon as it's thousands of coordinates, you are going to want to automate stuff.

As for the meaning of latestWkid, see here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013950

Answer (score 1):

Based on Berend, the quickest link is:

https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project

Then see it on google map

https://maps.google.com/?q=39.5785846502541+-105.071660830008

Answer (score 1):

For a formula that you can implement, see [this page](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) for an explanation and scroll down the bottom for various implemenations 3857 to/from 4326

Python Implementation provided:

```
def MetersToLatLon( mx, my ):
    "Converts XY point from Spherical Mercator EPSG:900913 to lat/lon in WGS84 Datum"

    lon = (mx / originShift) * 180.0
    lat = (my / originShift) * 180.0

    lat = 180 / math.pi * (2 * math.atan( math.exp( lat * math.pi / 180.0)) - math.pi / 2.0)
    return lat, lon
```

Comment: According to [article](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) mentioned in [Spcogg's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/351044/189093) originShift = 2 * math.pi * 6378137 / 2.0