# Getting lat/lng for latest Wkid:3435, Wkid:102671 and rings

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-server, geojson, arcgis-rest-api

I've seen similar question as [Getting lat/lng from wkid, latestwkid and x y coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278165/i-have-wkid-latestwkid-and-x-y-coordinates-i-need-lat-lng) but not sure how to put rings into ArcGIS server REST endpoint.

[image: enter "geometry": { "rings:" [ [1197289.1030000001, 1759877.251000002] [1197292.4299999997, 1759549.5487499982] [1197005.0549999997, 1759549.939000003] [1196998.6702499986, 1759968.4439999983] [1197288.1697500013, 1759969.0909999982] [1197289.1030000001, 1759877.251000002] ], "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon"} image description here]

Should I take every two coordinates and process separately? I am not really sure what output input/output spatial reference should be and why. Is there any Python program/package/code that can do it?

[image]

Comment: You can lop off seven decimal places (to make it millimeters, not ångströms), and nest another pair of brackets `[]`, so you have an array of rings, instead of a single ring.

Comment: It responds with; Polygon:
Ring0:[1197289.103,1759877.251],[1197292.429,1759549.548],[1197005.054,1759549.939]...3 more...

But I need Lat/Longitude as in google maps format of these points. Am I using a wrong converter?

Comment: There is a python package call 'pyproj' that can transform coordinates between different reference frames. (see https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/) If you want to couple it with geometry manipulation in python I suggest the 'shapely' library.